# How to parse the command output in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i'm creating a batch file to show my current power plan
i'm using this command:

```
powercfg -getactivescheme
```

it shows the result like this:

```
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
```

i want to hide the power plan code so it only shows:

```
(High performance)
```

any help is appreciated :D
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the standard [parse-loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```
for /f "delims=() tokens=2" %%a in ('powercfg -getactivescheme') do set name=%%a
echo Name: (%name%)
```